# Linear regression in R: testing statistical significance with t-tests

Tags: r, regression, t-test, finance

I am trying to test the statistical significance of the alphas in my trading strategy. However, I do not understand the difference between the alphas generated in R.

To test the statistical significance you run the regression

$$
R_{pt} - r_f= \alpha_P + \beta_P (R_{Mt}-r_f)+e_{Pt} 
$$

I interpret this as running the excess returns of the strategy on the l.h.s, and the returns predicted by the CAPM/market on the r.h.s., which is:

`lm(strategy - rf ~ alpha + beta*(market-rf)` (`lm()` is the regression function in R)

I use the package `PerformanceAnalytics` and function `CAPM.alpha()` which get the same alpha as when I do `summary((lm(strategy -rf ~ market - rf))`, where `market` is simply the historical returns from the market.

Which is the right method to test for the statistical significance (t-test, p-value etc.) of the alpha?

1. `lm(strategy - rf ~ alpha + beta*(market-rf)` (CAPM on rhs), or
2. `lm(strategy - rf ~ market - rf)`

I. $R_{pt} - r_f= \alpha_P + \beta_P (R_{Mt}-r_f)+e_{Pt}$

II. $R_{pt} - r_f = R_{Mt} - r_f$

The former method is statistically significant, while the latter is not. The results from the second method provide results consistent with previous literature (that alpha is not statistical significant with high p-values).

Comment: I don't know anything about the substantive matter of your question, but if I were to try to implement your first equation in R, I would use `lm(strategy ~ I(market - rf) + offset(rf)). The intercept (which is implicitly included in `lm`) would correspond to alpha.

Comment: Thank you! Then it seems like method 1. is not the right method, since the alpha and beta are included in the results of `lm()`.